# Adding parts of page title in web form and Master page

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, title

I have this Master page code near `<title>`:

```
<title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="title" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</title>
```

and in a web form that use this Master page I have this code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="title" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

How can I add some part of `title` of page in Master page code behind and other part of `title` in web form code behind that use this Maser page?

*since `<title>` does not accept inner tag ;I cant use some `<div>` to solve this.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correct, you would like to set the page title as combination of strings coming from the master page code behind and the content page code behind, right?

I would not use an `asp:Content` placeholder for that, but instead an `asp:Literal`.
This means you would need the following:

**MasterPage.Master:**

```
<title>
    <asp:Literal ID="TitleLiteral" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
</title>
```

**MasterPage.Master.cs:**

```
public void SetTitle(string text)
{
    TitleLiteral.Text = "my part of the title from master page" + text;
};
```

**ContentPage.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((MasterPage)Master).SetTitle("My part of the title from content page");
};
```

where `MasterPage` is the name of your master page (`public partial class MasterPage: System.Web.UI.MasterPage`).